# How to stop find command from listing folders with dot(.)

Tags: linux, find

In my home dir , i have folders like .cpan .cpcpan  and they are also showing.

How i hide them . i am using

```
find /home -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%f\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prune them.

```
find /home -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \( -name '.*' -prune -o -printf "%f\n" \)
```

Comment: can u please explain what does prune , -o does and what is the meaning of parenthesis

Comment: Consider this a golden opportunity to figure out how `man` works.